# how to draw rectangle around face in Image while capturing photo

Tags: android, camera, face-detection

in my current application I want to draw rectangle around face while capturing using Android device camera, and also want to save only face area inside rectangle on SD card.

I gone through lot of links like

[link1](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_Face_Detection)

[link2](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html)

[link3](https://github.com/wishygupta/Front-Camera-Android)

but unable to find proper solution.

Can anyone has worked on this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For Face Detection and eye detection there are many tutorial available on google.For that you can you OpenCV library or android default Face detection importing for that.Here is the link that can help you

> http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/

And if you are using eclipse then you also need to integrate ndk with eclipse to use above linked code